# @POST produces correct .zip archive from octet-stream through Postman, but invalid one through WebApp

Tags: javascript, java, angular, request, zip

I have method in JAVA that produces .zip:

```
@POST
@Path("download")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RequesterAccess(privileges = XXX})
public void downloadFiles(@Context HttpServletResponse resp, Request 
req) {
    resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    resp.setHeader(CONTENT_DISPOSITION_HEADER, 
"attachment;filename="xxx.zip");
    try {
        service.downloadFiles(resp.getOutputStream(), req);
(...)
```

While i execute POST through Postman and press Save and Download button, I receive valid .zip archive. When I try download it using WebBrowser and UI made in JavaScript - I get corrupted archive.

The requests and responses along with headers are identical.

Here is code responsible for file save in JS:

```
saveFile(apiFunction: Observable<any>) {

apiFunction.subscribe(
  data => {
    let contentDisposition = data.headers.get('content-disposition') || '';
    let matches = /filename=([^;]+)/ig.exec(contentDisposition);
    let fileName = (...)
    var blob = new Blob([data._body], {
      type: 'application/octet-stream'
    });
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName);
  }, error => {
(...)
```

In both screnarios, POST returns status code: 204. What can be the reason of broken archive ?

Edit:
I don't know much about JS, but the only difference I noticed between 2 POSTs is that before POST request from JS, there is some OPTIONS request made to the same endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Turned out, that archive had entries paths starting with "/", which worked fine on Linux through Postman, but Windows ZIP needs relative paths, therefore on Windows and in browsers archives were created/readed not properly.